# Running and monitoring batch processes in linux

Tags: linux, batch

I have about 4k processes that I need to run. All of them are quite resource intensive, so I have decided to batch them into 40 batches. All processes are independent for each other, and I want to run each batch after another. So far I decided to create 4000 systemd service files with `Type=oneshot`, and 40 targets. For each service I just put `RequiredBy={{random_batch}}`, and then I run 40 batches in a loop. I don't like this solution because it's difficult to monitor which processes have failed, which are running now, etc.

What are alternatives for this? What comes to mind is to use some queue system like celery and a Python script, but I would like to avoid any additional coding.

In a perfect world, I would love to use some "orchestrator" with some `MaxConcurrentJobs=40` parameter, which will automatically schedule jobs when there are available resources. K8S jobs come to mind, but it's hard to setup, and I would like to avoid any overhead.

Comment: What about `xargs -P 40 ...`?

Comment: "because it's difficult to monitor which processes have failed" -- wouldn't `systemctl list-units --failed` answer that question?